# Why do I get an unchecked cast warning on this generic type?

Tags: java, generics, types, casting, warnings

So here's my code :

```
public class SetWritable<T extends Writable> implements Writable {      
    private Class<? extends Writable> valueClass;
    private Set<T> values;  

    public SetWritable(Class<T> valueClass) {
        this.valueClass = valueClass;
        this.values = new HashSet<T>();
    }

        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        values = new HashSet<T>();          
        int len = in.readInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {         
            //this line is where I get the warning
            //FYI, WritableFactories.newInstance returns an instance of Writable
            T value = (T) WritableFactories.newInstance(valueClass);

            value.readFields(in);               
            values.add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

What's confusing to me is this : I've asserted that T extends Writable, so why am I getting a warning when I try to cast the Writable to T?  And since I know T extends Writable, is it safe to suppress this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the warning because `WritableFactories.newInstance` returns a `Writable` and your `T` **extends** `Writable`, so it *might* not be a safe cast. However, since you are using `Class<T>` as your argument to `newInstance` it is safe to suppress this warning.

It might be better to store `valueClass` as `Class<T>` and use [`Class#cast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) to cast for you, then you won't have any ugly `@SuppressWarnings` hanging over your method.

Comment: Good call!  And thanks for the speedy response.  Haven't used Class.cast before, but I think I like it!

Comment: @PaulBellora I don't use hadoop, but the [reference](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableFactories.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class)) I found showed `Writable`.

Comment: @Jeffrey - My mistake! I skimmed too quickly and assumed the OP was using Class#newInstance, completely missing the hadoop part.

Answer (score 3):

All `T`'s are `Writable`, but not all `Writable`s are `T`s.  So when you cast a `Writable` to `T`, it can't be sure that the `Writable` is *actually* a `T`.

For example, imagine there was an `S extends Writable`.  The `newInstance` might be an `S` and *not* a `T`, but it'd still be `Writable` -- but casting it to `T` would give you a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Nope, StackOverflow says mine was posted at 22:12:14, but yours was posted 30 seconds later at 22:12:44.  It's the other way around. ;)

Comment: Yes but I know for sure that I THOUGHT it first :-D

Answer (score 1):

All T's are Writable, but not all Writables are T's